React Native - How to download app and navigate to signup screen with pre-filled referral code by clicking on a referral link?
Guys i am working on a react native app. My app has a referral system. It uses referral code during registration.
Now i want to achieve the following:
When a person clicks on a referral link from mobile device, (if the app is already on the persons phone)it'll try to open the app and navigate to sign up screen with pre-filling the referral code or (If the person does not have the app) it'll try to open the app download screen in play/app store. Upon downloading & opening the app will recognise the referral code somehow and pre-fill it in registration form.
Is there any way to achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

If you configure deep linking and have the referral code as a param in the url, you can parse it. Here's react-navigation's documentation on it https://reactnavigation.org/docs/configuring-links/#passing-params

If you are using react navigation that whole page may actually be useful https://reactnavigation.org/docs/configuring-links/
